# SQL server to postgres migration : timestamp conversion issue

Tags: sql-server, casting, database-migration, postgresql-9.3

I have a data dump of a table from a SQL server, and I would like to import it into Postgres database. The generated file contains dates like this:

```
CAST(0x00009A78007FD81B AS DateTime)
```

This is limiting me from doing manual modifications to the SQL! Apparently that is the only column that is holding this simple migration process!

Other answers on the web don't show a work around! Here are the links I came across

[SqlServer to Postgres DDL migration/conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745667/sqlserver-to-postgres-ddl-migration-conversion)

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/46-Setting-up-PostgreSQL-as-a-Linked-Server-in-Microsoft-SQL-Server-64-bit.html

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't provide a cast from uint64 hex representation to timestamp. Can you use an ETL tool to handle the conversion?

Comment: @CraigRinger I would! can you suggest a free tool to use this?